# Communication Between Adapter and Activity?

Tags: android

I have a `listview` in the `layout`, and each item has two part: one is a user avatar (`ImageView`), and other is a chat content ( `TextView`). Looks like:

[image]

And I have a custom `adapter`.

I would like to implement :  when I click the avatar, I can go to the system gallery and select a photo as the avatar.

So my code about `onClickListener` in `adapter` class is:

```
 Intent itent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);


((Activity)(context)).startActivityForResult(itent, LOAD_IMAGE_RESULT);
```

And I also override the `onActivityResult` method in activity.

However, the solution I mentioned above cannot change the avatar in `onActivityResult` method, because I don't know how to communicate between `adapter` and `activity`.

Hope for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** - Initially, I have just shown one of the method to update **child views** only by leaving it's adapter in the inconsistent state (*because the original question don't give much information about underlying data structure*).

> **Adapter**: An Adapter object acts as a bridge between an AdapterView and the underlying data for that view. The Adapter provides access to
>   the data items. The Adapter is also responsible for making a View for
>   each item in the data set.

**Note:** *As the definition itself describes that it's important to maintain the state means (data + view). So you should always have the consistent user experience.*

To give the example properly, I have also defined the data model class `ItemData` based on the assumption of given image in original question.

```
/**
 * Model Class
 */  
public class ItemData {

    private Uri imageUri;
    private String msg;
    private Date timeStamp;

    public void setImageUri(Uri uri) {
        this.imageUri = uri;
    }

    public Uri getImageUri() {
        return this.imageUri;
    }

    ...
}
```

**CustomAdapter**

Create the custom adapter for listView which will maintain the child views with it's dataset accordingly. You've to maintain the reference of last selected row index `lastSelectedIndexRow` which can be used later for updating the view.

**Note:** *To get the view for any index in the `listView`, we should not call `getView()` method of the adapter. As calling `getView()` with null for the convertView causes the adapter to inflate a new view from the adapter's layout resource (does not get the view that is already being displayed).*

The **AdapterView** should always be updated with [notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) based on the current dataset hold by adapter.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    private List<ItemData> dataList;

    private int lastSelectedRowIndex = -1;
    public static int LOAD_IMAGE_RESULT = 201;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ItemData> dataList) {

        // hold the items
        this.context = context;
        this.dataList = dataList;

        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
         return (dataList != null && !dataList.isEmpty()) ? dataList.size() : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public ItemData getItem(int position) {
        return (dataList != null && !dataList.isEmpty()) ? dataList.get(position) : null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolderItem viewHolder;
        if (converView == null) {

             // inflate the layout
             convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);

             // well set up the ViewHolder
             viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
             viewHolder.avatar = (ImageButton)view.findById(R.id.avatar); 

             // store the holder with the view.
             convertView.setTag(viewHolder);    
        }
        else {
             // we've just avoided calling findViewById() on resource every time
             // just use the viewHolder
             viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // Set row data
        ItemData data = (ItemData)getItem(position);
        if (data != null) {

            // set message
            viewHolder.message.setText(data.getMessage());

            // set formatted timestamp
            String formattedTimeStamp = ...; // convert data.getTimeStamp() into formatted version
            viewHolder.timeStamp.setTextView(formattedTimeStamp);

            // set Image and also it's action.
            viewHolder.avatar.setImageUri(data.getImageUri());
            viewHolder.avatar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

               @Override
               public void onClick(View view) {
                  try {

                      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                      ((Activity)context).startActivityForResult(intent, LOAD_IMAGE_RESULT);
                  } catch (Exception e) {
                     Log.e("Demo application", "Failed to invoke call", e);
                  }
              }
           }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the last selected item index
     *
     */ 
    public int getLastSelectedItemIndex() {
       return lastSelectedRowIndex;
    }

    /**
     * Update the adapater with new data
     *
     */ 
    public void updateItems(List<ItemData> dataList) {

        if (this.dataList != dataList)
            this.dataList = dataList;

        // update the view.
        notifyDataSetChanged(); 

        // reset the last selection
        lastSelectedRowIndex = -1; 
    }

    /**
     * Hold View items 
     */   
    static class ViewHolderItem {

        private ImageView avatar;
        private TextView message;
        private TextView timeStamp;
    }
}
```

**ExampleActivity**

In activity, you've to defined the reference of custom adapter and handle the image selection results in `onActivityResult()` method. Once you get the selected image from gallery then update the underlying data holding inside `dataList` and also update the adapter by calling `updateItems()` custom method.

The `updateItems()` method of adapter will take the new data list as argument and invalidate the adapterView by calling [notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()).

```
public class ExampleActivity extend FragmentActivity {

     private ListView listView;
     private CustomAdapter adapter; 

     private List<ItemData> dataList;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         dataList = ...; // Load the list from database

         // Create the custom adapter with filled list items.
         adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, dataList);

         // List View and set the data adapter
         listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
         listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
         super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

         // Check if it's coming from MediaStore Selection.
         if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && 
                   requestCode == CustomAdapter.LOAD_IMAGE_RESULT) {

             // Get the selected rowIndex 
             if (adapter != null && dataList != null) {

                  // check the row index is valid
                  int rowIndex = adapter.getLastSelectedItemIndex();
                  if (rowIndex > -1 && rowIndex < dataList.size()) {

                       // Get the item
                       ItemData item = dataList.get(rowIndex);

                       // Update the item with imageUri
                       item.setImageUri(Uri.parse(data.getData()));

                       /**
                        * If you may want to update the information in database, 
                        * then it's the best place, but please do in background thread.
                        */

                      //Now notify the adapter with new changes
                      adapter.updateItems(dataList);
                  }
             }
         }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: This is all wrong. The adapter should always display it's current state, and need only be updated by a call to `notifyDataSetChanged`.

Comment: @PaulBurke - I agree, apparently the adapter should maintain the current state w.r.t data. And in order to achieve this, the data structure which hold the information to display list should update with new information and then invalidate the adapter by calling `notifyDataSetChanged`. However, the original question don't show the piece of code snippet that holds the information about "selected Image" so I have just showed one of the way to just update view only.

Comment: Rather than showing the OP how to make his bad code work, it would be more helpful to explain how to properly do this. Your answer is incomplete and incorrect from an Android perspective. What happens on config change, or if the system kills the app while paused?

Comment: As I said earlier, the "image selection" action not persist it's information so obviously all the changes will be lost in the case of config change, or system kills the app while paused (because activity will be recreated). Let me change my answer by defining the `ListData` model class.

Comment: That's my whole point: It's clear that the OP doesn't understand the way this all works. I will gladly up-vote if you advise on the model class (the proper way).

Comment: @PaulBuke - I've updated the answer. However, it's presumed that data items have been loaded/persisted from/to database. I haven't deal with database changes here.

Answer (score 0):

You should save a reference to the clicked view in the onClickListener method and have a public method in your adapter. When you get the response in the onActivityResult method call the adapter's method and use the

Answer (score -1):

In the adapter, (not sure which kind of adapter you using), you set the onClickListener for the ImageView. Hence,

```
mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                <INSERT CODE HERE>
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Where mImageView is the ImageView for that item. Also a good idea might be to use an ImageButton since it allows Images and is a button which is what you want. Then by the  add the code you want to select the Image. You may need to pass context through to the Adapter too (but you would generally do that anyway). Then you can process the onActivityResult method in the activity that the adapter is in i.e. setting the Image to the image you picked. There are a couple ways to do this.

Comment: What troubles is : after I click the avatar, and select a photo, how I   update the avatar in "onActivityResult" method?

Answer (score -1):

Add a public method in your custom adapter to set the image (like `public void setAvatar(Bitmap image)`)

Then, in your `onActivityResult` method, get the image selected and use your newly created method to set the new image in your adapter. (see here for more informations: [Getting a Result from an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Don't forget to put `notifyDataSetChanged();` at the end of your your newly method in your adapter to refresh all the list.

```
public void setAvatar(Bitmap image)
{
    ...

    imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
    ...

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

In addition, if you need to know which image was clicked, you can specify an `Integer` as a parameter and check it in the `onActivityResult`.
I see you use a constant `LOAD_IMAGE_RESULT` for this parameter. Instead of a constant, put an integer who identify the clicked item.

Comment: I have to know which item is clicked in onActivityResult method. But How can I get it ? Must I have global variable to represent this ?

Comment: Extract from android dev website:  
_There's nothing special about the Intent object you use when starting an activity for a result, but you do need to pass an additional integer argument to the startActivityForResult() method.

The integer argument is a "request code" that identifies your request. When you receive the result Intent, the callback provides the same request code so that your app can properly identify the result and determine how to handle it._
I'll edit my answer. In waiting, see this: [dev page](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html#StartActivity)